# How does bit.ly do their zero clipboard implementation?

Tags: jquery, flash, zeroclipboard

When copying a link on bit.ly they use an interesting flash effect.  I have created a [screencast](http://youtu.be/6Dtvl4rYXLE) on the topic. I am wondering how to go about implementing this effect.

If anyone knows of a simple way to implement zero clipboard please reply. I have found zero clipboard to be tough to implement without issues.

Comment: I think you should give a try looking in the code. For sure, it is some HTML element having its Y absolute position decreased.

Comment: I have looked at the code, just can't figure it out. Zero Clipboard has confusing behavior to comprehend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about this effect: http://jsfiddle.net/6XfMs/6/ ? It's easy to implement using jQuery animation:

```
jQuery('#element').animate(
{
   opacity: 0,
   top: '-=100',
}, 500);
```

Comment: @valentinas bitly doesn't completely fade out the element(link). How can you get the exact same effect?

Comment: Adjust the opacity to get the desired result.